# example of convergent series, positive sequence, not decreasing

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

I would like to see an example of sequence $x_n$ such that  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x_n$ is convergent where all $x_n \ge 0$, $x_n$ is not decreasing and $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}n x_n \neq  0$$.

(I changed the initial text because I got confused during writing it, and it didn't make sense)

Comment: You can modify your example slightly to get a convergent series.  Can you see how?

Comment: i'm sorry I got confused while writing it. I made the question clear now.

Comment: Ah, that is a very different question.  Hint:  Choose $x_n = 1/n$ for $n \in A$, $x_n = 0$ for $n \notin A$, for a suitable set $A$.

Comment: but the series won't be convergent anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $x_{2^{n}}=1/2^{n}$ and $x_{k}=0$ otherwise, then $2^{n}x_{2^{n}}=1$, so $(nx_{n})$ contains a subsequence which does not converge to zero.